# I want to know,when startOffsetTime`s value is kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime().the offset value is what?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When I set `startOffsetTime=kafka.api.OffsetRequest.LatestTime()`, the offset`s value is the largest available.

When set `startOffsetTime is kafka.api.OffsetRequest.EarliestTime()` what is the offset value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand your question a little bit. But anyway I suppose you are asking what offset will be when you query the earliest offset.

Kafka has log retention configurations that allow to set time to live for a message or log file size. [More here](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html).

Imagine you have a topic with log retention hours set to 1 hour and you produce some messages with following offsets:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

After one hour old messages will be removed from log and you may get a following picture:

```
<offsets 0 1 2 3 4 no more exist in log> 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Then when you will query for earliest offset you will get `5` as offsets `0-4` no more exist.

The same applies for `log.retention.bytes` config, when you exceed that configuration value, older messages will be dropped (whole segment actually, but that doesn't matter for this question) resulting in earliest offset to be higher than `0`.